# C# using two different equality comparers

Tags: c#

I need to write a second equality comparer for a business object. It is a specialized equality comparer which is only applicable in certain situations. I do not want to override the Equal() because our persistent layer uses that to compare objects internally for its own uses.
Let me give you an example of a class:

```
public class Product : BusinessObjectBase
{
    string Name  {get;set;}
    string Desc  {get;set;}
    double Price {get;set;}
}
```

Since we mark the three properties as persistent data properties in our data access layer, the Equals() in the BusinessObjectBase compares those properties. Now, in a specific instance I would like to check if product A it equal to product B only be Name. I do not want to hardcode the actual property on the check because this property might change later.

While IComparer could be used here, but based on the description on MSDN, IComparer should be used not to equate items but to sort them, so that does not seem like a 100% correct answer.
I would like to use something .NET already has and not create another interface.
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It already exists: guess the name ? [IEqualityComparer !](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) ;)

Comment: you are saying "product A it equal to product B only be Name. I do not want to hardcode the actual property on the check because this property might change late" .How do you compare 2 objects without specifying the Name property and using ONLY IEqualityComparer<T>. Do you use reflection in the Equals Method or what is so special in the  IEqualityComparer<T> which makes you to do that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @Slaks: i understand  your answer, i am just curious and also read my comment and my question is what is so special in this interface which will solve his problem?How his cannot be done using IComparer /

Comment: @1010101: `IEqualityComparer<T>` includes `GetHashCode(T)`, making it usable for hashtables.  It's also possible to implement for types that aren't ordered.